# Is this the right development approach in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to know, if I am following the best practices of development in CakePHP framework.

If you have for a example an Invoices Table, and you want to display the status of the Invoice, let's say you want a green label for the status of the invoice like this:

```
<span class="green">Paid</span>
```

What i do is the following. I create a virtualfield on my model named statuslabel, in that virtualfield i call a Helper that displays an element.

so it would be Model->Helper->Element

That way anywhere in my application i can call statuslabel like it was a field from that model and i would get the statuslabel.

My big question is if this is the right way to do it or i am doing it all wrong?

Comment: I just use tinyint2 and ["enums"](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) and a simple view helper to format it. I would not modify the model layer here at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid violating the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) principles in your code, in this case specifically containing presentation logic in the model code. This equally applies to CakePHP and other MVC frameworks.

You might still go ahead and create a virtual field called `status` which can calculate the status of your invoice based on other entity fields. If you have the status stored in the database already as a normal entity field, then you can skip the virtual field.

The view layer is where you want all your presentation code. You can either do it directly in views, or move the logic to the helper. The appropriate function in the helper would take your status field as input and output the appropriate classes into the template based on the status value.

The advantage of keeping presentation code in the view layer (template and helper classes in CakePHP) is that it is easy to replace it later on by updating your templates. CakePHP 3 also gives you the option to create [themes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html) via plugins, which is how you can easily change the UI of your application on the fly, but only if you stick to the design principles of MVC.

Comment: Well the html is on a template file being called from a helper, what i do is pass the data from my model to my helper, is that violating the MVC principle?

Comment: You cannot pass the data from your model to the helper. I think you are expressing yourself badly - what you probably mean is that the controller fetches the data, passes it to the view, and the template itself calls the helper and passes the model data then into it. Which is all fine.

Comment: The problem here is that you seem to pass not only the data, but also the presentation logic. It is fine if you pass the status as a string value, e.g. `"Paid"`. Data is taken from the model by the controller and then put into the view. In your helper class you should have the logic to state:

Comment: `if ($status == "Paid") { echo ' class="green"'; }`

Sorry for splitting the answer into two comments unintentionally. I hope you see the difference vs. putting this logic into a model, which would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Generally using virtual fields are not an bad idea. Sometimes the logic behind simple answer is quite complex that it can not be done via SQL or with reasonable amount of SQL.

It is important to remember, that most of the time, using queries directly is much faster without extra PHP processing. So for what comes to your question, if you don't have any PHP logic (besides generating SQL expressions), I would say go with it but...

...There is also point for discussion about database design.

I can't really say about your database schema behind the question, but for me such simple thing than invoice status should definitely be in database directly as and int type field. So what comes to my experience about invoicing systems, database schema could be something like:

## invoices

- id
- invoice_status_id

## invoice_statuses

- id
- title

If you create your model associations and query your database correctly, you end up having invoice status in query results and you can use it just like described.

Btw. most of the time, using reusable elements is good practice. Less code to maintain :D